# Smallest int value that is smaller than the smallest representable int?

Tags: c++, integer, comparison, minimum

`std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` returns 0 if `T` is an integral type. Is there a replacement for this function that I can use? I have a series of int variables (they could be `int8, uint8, int32, uint32, int64, uint64`) that could take on values anywhere between their minimum (inclusive) and maximum (inclusive) values.

I need a value that is smaller than all of these variables, and this value will be used to comparison purposes (I would be comparing whether this value is smaller than my series of int variables).

I know I could something like `-std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`, but if I were to compare my int variables with this value, the comparison would be done in FP precision, and I'm concerned about the performance implications of that. I would, ideally, like all the comparisons to be done with integers.

I think the smallest int value that we can have is `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::minimum()`, so I think my question is essentially asking if we can get an integer value smaller than this?

Comment: Only if you have `int128_t` availabe to you, I suppose. And when you have that, at some point you'll want to know if `int256_t` lurking in the shadows. And so on, it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: If the value you are checking is below the sought-for limit, then it can't be represented as an integer; so, how would you expect to use it in an integer comparison?

Comment: @roulette01 It seems what you are trying to do does not make a sense.

Comment: Instead of using a sentinal value, you can use `std::optional` and leave it empty if the wrapped integer has no actual value.

Comment: But what would you compare to that? If you have a value smaller than smallest `int64`, the comparison with both `int64` and `uint64` would always result in "greater than".

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own minus infinity constant that compares less than any other value.

This is less tedious with [C++20's three way comparator (aka spaceship)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison), but feasible in previous versions:

```
#include <compare>

struct minus_infinity_t {} constexpr minus_infinity;

auto constexpr operator<=> (minus_infinity_t, minus_infinity_t)
{ return std::weak_ordering::equivalent; }
template<class T> auto constexpr operator<=> (T, minus_infinity_t)
{ return std::weak_ordering::greater; }
template<class T> auto constexpr operator<=> (minus_infinity_t, T)
{ return std::weak_ordering::less; }


int main()
{
    constexpr int n = 0;
    constexpr long long k = 1;
    constexpr double l = 2;
    
    static_assert(n > minus_infinity);
    static_assert(k > minus_infinity);
    static_assert(l > minus_infinity);
    
    static_assert(minus_infinity <= n);
    static_assert(minus_infinity <= k);
    static_assert(minus_infinity <= l);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35d43716717d383f)

---

Improvement ideas:

- Restrict what `T` can be with concepts
- Define a positive infinity
- Define a negative and positive zero

Comment: Drawback: you cannot have a collection of, say, `int`s containing `minus_infinity`.

Comment: I think this'll work. Is it possible to extend this idea so that I can have minus_infinity be returned from std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()? the return type is `T`, so I'm not sure how it can be done

Comment: Not possible i'm afraid. You'd have to wrap all calls to infinity into your own `numeric_limits` and call that everywhere.

Comment: @roulette01 Is this a one-time thing, or do you want this behavior throughout the program? For one-time thing, you can do something like `std::conditional<std::integral<T>, minus_infinity_t, std::numeric_limits<T>>::infinity()`. Otherwise, you might need to create your own `My_Numeric_Limits<T>` type, and use that throughout your program.